# (ionic) Image on 50% of the screen

Tags: javascript, image, css, ionic-framework

This is what I get when I try to put the image between the navbar and half of the screen.
I'd like to know how put the full image on 50% of the screen, just below of the others 50% which are buttons.
Any solution in CSS ? or ionic ?

[image]

Comment: Since questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself, __I voted to close this question as it hasn't fulfilled that.__ Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: which versonof ionic are you using 1 or 2?

Comment: have you tried image width="100%" it will work

Comment: ionic 1 and why should apply something on the width ?